# Changing tabs with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm attempting at changing the background color of the td's on click. This is what I currently have for JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#leftHoldNav table td').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('highlight');
    $this.parent().siblings('table').find('td').removeClass('highlight');
});
});
```

This is what I have for the HTML:

```
    <div id="leftHoldNav">
    <center>
    <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
    <tr>
        <td onclick="loadPage('../about/info.php','#mainWrapLoad','../about/')" class="highlight">Info</td>
        <td onclick="loadPage('../about/kcintl.php','#mainWrapLoad','../about/')" class="">KC Int'l</td>
        <td onclick="loadPage('../about/board.php','#mainWrapLoad','../about/')" class="">Board</td>
        <td onclick="loadPage('../about/dcon.php','#mainWrapLoad','../about/')" class="">D-Con</td>
    </tr>
    </table>
    </center>
    </div>
```

It's not working, anybody have an idea why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://jsbin.com/inogov/1/edit

you don't need to go back to `parent`, stay on the `siblings`.

```
$this.siblings('td').removeClass('highlight');
```

There you go:

```
$('#leftHoldNav table td').click(function(){
    var $this = $(this);
    $this.addClass('highlight').siblings('td').removeClass('highlight');
});
```

Comment: It seems to be functioning properly now. Thanks so much!

Comment: @JakeMartinez you're welcome! hope the chained methods are clear... :)